# Magento, redirect URLs with index.php to URLs without it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I am setting up a Magento website which is not inside of any sub-directory such as `/shop`.

Before every URL on the website had the `index.php` append next to the domain name, for e.g the admin panel was `example.com/index.php/admin`.

I enabled Mod_rewrite in Magento's admin panel and added an `.htaccess` file with the following to make sure that `example.com/admin` actually goes to the admin panel and so on. It does work.

Here's the `htaccess` configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that when I manually type `example.com/index.php/admin` it takes me to the admin panel as expected but the URL stays that, I expected it to redirect to the right URL which is `example.com/admin` but I am not able to.

Do I have to add any configurations to the `htaccess` or is it Magento related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following rewrite rules to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This will check if the url contains `index.php` and if it does then redirect to the url without index.php.